# How to factory reset Windows 10 version 1607

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I've got a machine that needs to have a factory reset with all the data wiped before the machine leaves the premises.  From searching the Internet, I find that I am supposed to go to Settings > Update & Security > Reset your PC.

However, under Update & Security I do not see a "Reset you PC" option.  I see "Advanced Startup (Restart now)" and "More Recovery Options" which only has a link to "Learn how to start fresh with a clean installation of Windows".  However, this machine does not have Internet or network access.  I find it rather strange that an Internet connection would be needed to wipe a machine that we have no more use for!  For what it's worth I also do not have any media for the device, nor do I have the time to track anything down.

This machine is running Windows 10 Home, Version 1607, OS Build 14393.2189.  Is it possible to easily do a factory reset/wipe, or am I going to have to go for a more destructive approach?

Comment: The built in methods of Windows are not for erasing data but for resetting Windows. Depending if you have an HDD and SSD or an SSD with secure erase feature there are other ways to really erase data.

Comment: If you use the Manufacturer's USB to return to factory settings, all data, profiles and apps will be gone. That is likely good enough. Otherwise use one  of the erasure apps.

Comment: @John don't have a manufacturer's USB or erasure app

Comment: Get an erasure app and delete the disk so nothing is left. No big deal for a buyer / receiver to get a Windows license. You can make a Windows install key from most systems. Erase the data and put the key with it.

Comment: @John I'd rather just destroy the device.  Honestly it's less cost and effort (the machine has very low value, I would just rather recycle it than demolish it)

Comment: Take the disk out, drill holes through and recycle the lot. We do this at customers frequently. No point to keep the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Windows resets only reset the settings of Windows. They do not wipe any user data.

As you are looking to retire the computer, the best and cheapest method of protecting your data in that process is to physically remove and destroy the hard drive, taking particular care to destroy the usually shiny platters inside the drive if it's a spinny drive, and the chips on the PCBs, if its an SSD.

Answer (score 1):

If the disk has critical PII or proprietary info, then as other state, physically destroy it (though there are some useful part, such as magnets, you might salvage).

However, for less critical disk wiping, there are a plethora of free tools, such as [PrivaZer](https://privazer.com/) and [CCleaner free](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download) with disk wipers that will do a fairly thorough job, rewriting each byte a number of times. That said, the process inevitably takes a **long** time, i.e., days. However, that leaves you with a disk on which an OS can be installed, whether Windows or Linux.